# Keyboard Shortcut for Moving Between Words in Camel Case in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

In Notepad++, is there a keyboard shortcut for moving between the compound words in a [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) word?  When I use the shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Right/Left</kbd>, the caret moves to the next "real" word, not the next compound word.

Comment: As far as I know, out of the box there isn't. Not sure if any plugins out there fill this gap though.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/4420091 ?

Comment: Ahh, I looked through the shortcuts but didn't see that.  Thanks, Cygal!

Comment: @Cygal: Maybe you should quote that in an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- Right : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>
- Left : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>

---

Source: http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/bf4ad0f5. Here is the interesting bit:

> You can.  Set the shortcuts in the shortcut mapper (Scintilla Commands
>   tab) for SCI_WORDPARTLEFT, SCI_WORDPARTRIGHT.   The "EXTEND" versions
>   of these shortcuts normally have the shift key added, as they "extend"
>   the selection, so it's natural to hold shift down in these cases.

Comment: I'd also add that, by default, it's set to Control + \ to go right and Control + / to go left.

Comment: Man, in my 4 years of using Notepad++ I never thought to look in Settings > Shortcut Mapper...

Comment: also worth mentioning, note that you must also remove the binding to other accelerators using the shortcut you choose, usually SCI_WORDLEFT, SCI_WORDLEFTEXTEND, SCI_WORDRIGHT, SCI_WORDRIGHTENDEXTEND

Comment: Hmmm, there doesn't seem to be a shortcut for SCI_DELWORDPARTLEFT etc, so I don't seem to be able to configure exactly the behaviour I want.

Comment: As @kfiroo pointed out, If you want to map `Ctrl` (+ `Shift`) + `Left`/`Right` to use the camel humps, you have to change (for some unknown reason I couldn't delete them) the bindings for their "old" commands (i.e. the ones he listed)