# Case change as word boundary in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard Shortcut for Moving Between Words in Camel Case in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862511/keyboard-shortcut-for-moving-between-words-in-camel-case-in-notepad)

Is it possible to use case change as a word boundary in Notepad++?  For example, if the cursor is at the start of "myVariableFoo", then `<CTRL-Right>` moves the cursor in front of "Variable" then in front of "Foo".

Comment: You can set what key combination you like via: Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Scintilla commands > SCI_WORDPARTLEFT/SCI_WORDPARTRIGHT. The defaults are `ctrl + \ ` and `ctrl + /`

Comment: Thanks @veredesmarald! Make that into an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set whatever key combination you like to do this via:

`Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Scintilla commands > SCI_WORDPARTLEFT/SCI_WORDPARTRIGHT.`

The defaults are `ctrl + \` and `ctrl + /`